# Mongodb - Return embeded data acording by conditions

Tags: mongodb

i am new in mongodb and what i found are only exaples for basic case.
Unfortunately, neither the manual was not helpful.

I need get response with filtered data from embed document for example:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "615c74d32f86c312a50da3d2"
    },
    "basic_column": "post number 1",
    "basic_column": "lorem ipsum",
    "embededData": [{
        "date": {
            "$date": "2021-11-05T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "embeded_column_1": 23
    }, {
        "date": {
            "$date": "2022-11-06T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "embeded_column_1": 24
    }]
},{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "618c74d32f86c312a50da3d2"
    },
    "basic_column": "post number 2",
    "basic_column": "lorem ipsum",
    "embededData": [{
        "date": {
            "$date": "2021-11-05T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "embeded_column_1": 25
    }, {
        "date": {
            "$date": "2021-11-06T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "embeded_column_1": 26
    }]
}
```

i need from this get result where is condition for "basic_column" = "lorem ipsum" and have in "embededData" documents only for "date" > 2020 and "date" < 2022

so result should be

```
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "615c74d32f86c312a50da3d2"
        },
        "basic_column": "post number 1",
        "basic_column": "lorem ipsum",
        "embededData": [{
            "date": {
                "$date": "2021-11-05T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "embeded_column_1": 23,
        }]
    },{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "618c74d32f86c312a50da3d2"
        },
        "basic_column": "post number 2",
        "basic_column": "lorem ipsum",
        "embededData": [{
            "date": {
                "$date": "2021-11-05T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "embeded_column_1": 25,
        }, {
            "date": {
                "$date": "2021-11-06T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "embeded_column_1": 26
        }]
    }
```

thank you for help

Comment: You can't get the same name in two keys (i.e. `basic_column`) in JSON. Your data is not valid.

Comment: Try using `$filter`

Comment: keys are different "615... vs "618.. and these data are for sample only sry for confusing

Comment: with $filter I'm capable get only all document acording by condition from embed data but i am not capable get document with filtered embed data ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- match to keep only documents that have `"basic_column" = "lorem ipsum"`
- filter and keep only the members with year of date >2020 < 2022
  ($year operator is used to do this)
- if you want to filter out document that have empty embeddedData add this also
  `{"$match": {"$expr": {"$ne": ["$embededData", []]}}}`

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NMm_L3XyHdT)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": {"basic_column": {"$eq": "lorem ipsum"}}},
  {"$set": 
    {"embededData": 
      {"$filter": 
        {"input": "$embededData",
          "cond": 
          {"$let": 
            {"vars": {"date_year": {"$year": "$$this.date"}},
              "in": 
              {"$and": 
                [{"$gt": ["$$date_year", 2020]},
                  {"$lt": ["$$date_year", 2022]}]}}}}}}}])
```

Comment: it is helpful thank you 
please can you help me why dont work my example for condition on all datetime 

https://mongoplayground.net/p/M6YYaknaP4_

it is my first question on stackoverflow so i am not sure if it is not for new question/topic or is good way extend this issue in next comment 

I will be glad for any knowledge that will improve my decision making in the future

Comment: i think [this is ok](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ULRrgPKHTdY) it was small mistake i think, you had an extra `{"in" : ...}`  in previous example the `in ` was part of the let not part of the filter, check it  if all ok.

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent npm [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath) for making queries on JSON.
And also, `basic_column` appears twice in a dictionary, which is invalid. Each key should be unique in a dictionary.

Comment: thank you i need then receive these data trought mongodb realm as graphql request but this is step number one for me .. i need know if that's even possible in this case in mongo database

Comment: That wasn't a part of your initial question.